# iOS app gets terminated while playing music in background

Tags: ios, react-native, ios11

I've developed an iOS music player which plays own music files in background mode. The app is based on React Native 0.48 and uses some third party plugins like [music controls](https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control) and [audio-toolkit](https://github.com/futurice/react-native-audio-toolkit) as sound library.

Since I've installed iOS 11 on my device I'm having the following problem: When I play music in background mode, the app gets terminated after 10-15 minutes with the following message:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9
```

This didn't happen on iOS 10, on this older iOS version, the app run fine in background mode. I've also set the correct background modes:

[image]

Memory and CPU usage look normally, couldn't find anything special compared to iOS 10:

[image]
[image]

The iPhone has about 500 MB free RAM the whole time. Are there any changes between iOS 10 and iOS 11 that could cause this issue?

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue, on iOS 11 simulator, audio stops playing immediatelly after app goes to background. File a bug report on bugreport.apple.com :)

Comment: Yeah, just thought about it today. I'm doing it right know, I hope  this is a bug and not a "new feature".

Comment: @DavidRiha but it is interesting that it doesn't happen on the Spotify app. So I don't know if this could be an performance issue with React Native.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/futurice/react-native-audio-toolkit/blob/master/docs/API.md) provided, it is already mentioned that playing audio in the background on iOS isn't currently supported by this native module.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the [background timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) plugin. After removing it, everything worked fine again. I guess that this plugin activates some background mode too and iOS kills the app because of the (long running) job.

Answer (score 0):

I got below bugfix from other forum:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2387025

No code changes are needed to make this work on compile.

Run the following (tested on 2.1 & 2.1.4-stable branches):
scons p=iphone -j 4 target=release tools=no arch=arm64 bits=64 IPHONESDK="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/"

The important part is pointing the iPhoneSDK to the symlinked location instead.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/
```

Now when the app is suspended/backgrounded, it will not crash and resumes as expected :)